# Assigned variable for pipeline is not working

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a shell script to check port status. After checking the port if it is busy then will kill it.

```
#check port and kill
checkPort(){
     check=$(sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 2020 | awk '{print $6}')
    word="LISTEN"
    killProcess=$(sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 2020 | awk '{print $7}' |
                  sed 's/.\{5\}$//' | sort -u |  xargs -t kill -9)
    if [[ "$check" == "$word"  ]];
    then
        echo "killing the port 2020"
        $killProcess
     else
        echo "Not Listen"
    fi
}
```

When I run the `$killProcess` variable I am getting errors. But if I put the full command as `sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 2020 | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/.\{5\}$//' | sort -u |  xargs -t kill -9` inside the `if` condition, it is working fine. What would be the mistake here?

The errors I get:

```
kill -9 

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid|name> [...]

Options:
 -a, --all              do not restrict the name-to-pid conversion to processes
                        with the same uid as the present process
 -s, --signal <sig>     send specified signal
 -q, --queue <sig>      use sigqueue(2) rather than kill(2)
 -p, --pid              print pids without signaling them
 -l, --list [=<signal>] list signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list signal names and numbers

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit
```

I put `xargs -i kill -kill {}` instead of `xargs kill -9`. Works fine. Is it a good practice?

Comment: What is `$killProcess` supposed to be? Here it's the output of `xargs kill -9` - is that what you intended? The script as written will run `xargs kill -9` in the command substitution before the `if` check.

Comment: yes I got it. I put  `xargs -i kill -kill {}` instead of `xargs kill -9`. Works fine

Comment: @Janith no, that isn't the problem. The main issue is that you are running the `kill` in the first variable assignment (`killProcess=$(...)`), the `if` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `var=$(command)` will run `command` and assign its output to the variable `$var`. This means that this line in your script:

```
killProcess=$(sudo netstat -nlpt | grep 2020 | awk '{print $7}' |
              sed 's/.\{5\}$//' | sort -u |  xargs -t kill -9)
```

will *always* run this pipeline which ends with the `kill` command, and assign its output to `$killprocess`. Since the `kill` command has no output, this line later will never do anything:

```
$killProcess
```

What you want to do is `killProcess="sudo netstat ... | xargs -t kill -9`. But there are other issues with your command as well. First of all, it will match any lines containing 2020, but you only want cases where `2020` is the port. What if it is the PID instead?

Here is a working version of your function with a few changes:

```
checkPort(){
  ## Get the target port. If none is given, default to 2020
  targetPort=${1:-2020}

  ## Collect the PID(s) that are listening on the port in the
  # array 'pids'.
  pids=( $(sudo netstat -nlpt | awk "\$4~/:$targetPort\$/{print \$7}" |
           sed 's|/.*||'))
  ## If no processes were listening, move on
  if [[ -z ${pids[0]} ]];
  then
    echo "No process listening on port $targetPort"
  ## If any processes were listening, kill them.
  else
    echo "killing process(es) listening on port $targetPort"
    ## First, try to kill the process gracefully
    kill "${pids[@]}"
    ## Check if any are still running
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
      ## If it is still running
      if kill -0 "$pid"; then
        ## Kill it with fire
        kill -9 "$pid"
      fi
    done
  fi
}
```

This can now take a parameter, so run it as `checkport` to check port 2020, and `checkport 22` will check port 22. It also first tries to kill gracefully (ou should always avoid `kill -9` unless absolutely necessary) and only uses `kill -9` if that fails.

Comment: this script works fine.